# Diagrams in reveal.js

Tags: diagram, reveal.js

I'm currently creating a presentation with the awesome [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/)

I want to add a fancy diagram (something like this) to the presentation:
[image]

but I didn't find any plugins to do this. Does anyone know a solution?

I want to avaoid using a screenshot...

Comment: There is a basic [mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/demos.html) plugin for reveal.js on github: [ludwick/reveal.js-mermaid-plugin](https://github.com/ludwick/reveal.js-mermaid-plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reveal.js** has no official plugins to support this feature. The fastest solution is to create diagrams in SVG and include as images